# Share variables between functions

Tags: python-3.x, variables

I want to share variables between two functions: from the bottom one to the top one

```
def number_function():
   print(number_1)
   print(number_2)

number_function()

def test():
   number_1=10
   number_2=20
```

When I have tried to run the code I get this error

```
NameError: name 'number1' is not defined
```

Comment: Variables are scoped to functions. If you want to access those variables, `test()` should return them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are "undefined variable" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Mark Meyer, the variables are scoped to functions and there is no way for variables inside `test` to exist if you do not call the function `test()` function.

In case you do run `test()` and don't want to return and pass variables to other functions, you would need to define the variables as `global`, so they are not confined to the function scope.

```py
def test():
    global number_1
    global number_2
    number_1=10
    number_2=20

def number_function():
    print(number_1)
    print(number_2)

test()
number_function()

Out[1]:
10
20
```

Another way to share variables across functions is to simply use classes:

```py
Class yourEnv(object):

    def __init__(self):
         self.number_1 = 10
         self.number_2 = 20

    def number_function(self):
        print(self.number_1)
        print(self.number_2)

yourEnv().number_function()

Out[2]
10
20
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer .

Comment: can i do the reverse?, for example :

Answer (score 0):

can id do the reverse ?, for example :

```
def test():
    print(number_1)
    print(number_2)        

def number_function():

    global number_1
    global number_2
    number_1=10
    number_2=20
test()
number_function()
```

Comment: Variables have to be defined first, how can you print them if they do not exist yet?

Comment: Okay thank you , i thought it was a way to did it but i find out that i must define the first.